# Can python interpret lists in text files?

Tags: python, list, file

I am trying to make a password keeper and I have the usernames and passwords of the user accounts in a text file. However, since the script wants to know if the user input for loginUser and loginPass are in the file, that creates the opportunity for the user to log in with mismatched usernames and passwords. Can I create a list (or at least a pair of strings) and check if the input for the login variables are in a specific list?

Here's my code If you want to test it yourself:

```
def title():
    # This is the title screen
    print('____This is a password keeper____')
    main()


def main():
    abc = open("userpassfile.txt", "r+")
    userpassfile = abc.read().strip().split()
    actCheck = input('Do you already have an account?')
    if(actCheck == 'Yes' or actCheck == 'yes'):
        loginUser = input('What is your username?')
        loginPass = input('What is yout password?')
        if(loginUser and loginPass in userpassfile):
            dirCheck = input('Account Settings? [y/n]')
            if(dirCheck == 'y' or dirCheck == 'Y'):
                print('This function is not working yet!')
            else:
                print('hihi')
        else:
            print('Incorrect password or username!')
    else:
        createAct = input('would you like to create one?')
        if (createAct == 'Yes' or createAct == 'yes'):
            createUser = input('What would you like your username to be?:')
            createPass = input('What would you like your password to be?:')
            abc.write(createUser + '\n')
            abc.write(createPass + '\n')
            open(createUser + '.txt', "w")

title()
```

If you have any questions about my code, please ask! Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that a password file that can be read by the user who authenticates, is not secure at all?

Comment: As @KlausD. says above, please be aware that this is not at all remotely secure. You are storing passwords in plaintext, and also reading them from a file (which they probably shouldn't be in, in the first place). 

I really hope this is only for personal use. Even then, be careful saving your passwords in plaintext. Look into some basic cryptography; it's actually really fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it would make more sense to store the user / pass pairs in a single line.  Something like

```
user:pass
```

Or

```
user|pass
```

The problem with this approach is that you eliminate a character, the one used as the delimiter, from being used in your username or password.  To get around that limitation, you can do something similar to how strings protocol works and prepend the line with a number representing the length of the username.

```
004userpass
014longerusernamepassword
```

You read the first 3 characters as an integer, and know how many more to read for the user and how many for the password.

Of course you could also store it in several other formats like json, yaml, or csv,

Given that you are storing them in pairs of lines, you should be able to break them up into their groups with code similar to this:

```
f = """username1
password1
username2
password2""".splitlines()

pairs = [tuple(f[i*2:i*2+2]) for i in range(len(f)/2)]
print(pairs)
```

This would output:

```
[('username1', 'password1'), ('username2', 'password2')]
```

Then you would simply check

```
if (loginUser, loginPass) in pairs:
    ...
```

You could use a more generic approach for breaking your list of usernames / passwords into pairs as well with this function

```
def groups(inval, size):
    for i in range(0, len(inval), size):
        yield inval[i:i+size]
```

And you could then do

```
pairs = tuple(groups(f, 2))
```

Comment: I'm trying to save all of the usernames and passwords in a separate text file. How would I create a list in the file and check if the input for loginUser and loginPass are in the same list, in the file?

Comment: Instead of the `f` I have defined, you would use `f = abc.read().splitlines()` then everything else is the same.